# Accepted Job Offer, Now No Contact

Tags: job-offer

I interviewed for a position at a small non-profit in my town about 3 weeks ago. I accepted an offer through Email and all went well. We were discussing the specifics of the job, and she told me an estimate of when the job would start. She seemed very excited to work alongside me. I told her my availability and asked what paperwork I needed to complete about a week ago- just to touch base, but she still has not responded. I'm starting to worry.

Should I start interviewing for different positions, or am I being paranoid?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does this mean that he has been put 'on hold'?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115791/does-this-mean-that-he-has-been-put-on-hold)

Answer (score 15):

Keep interviewing until you have a signed offer that you're happy with. Worst case scenario is that you end up with several offers to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

I like PeteCon's answer in that there is no harm in continuing to explore your options.

I wanted to add that the non-profits I have observed tend to run lean on staff and, depending on their model, go feast or famine on their workload. It would not surprise me that the person in charge of on-boarding you is the same person that organizes the decorations at the yearly fundraiser, pays the utility bills, fights for government grants, travels to give seminars, etc, etc...

Point is, I wouldn't be worried just yet as this could simply be a crunch time week for this person.  If I were in this situation, I would probably do a gentle follow up email once a week or so.. maybe attempt a call to get an answer. If three attempts like this go by with no response from the company, I would just drop it and progress to focusing on the next interview process.

Comment: It is a VERY small non profit. It opened only a few years ago.There are only about 5-10 MAX on staff. The CEO is the hiring manager, grant writer, and everything else. I know that she is extremely busy. I believe she just hasn't had time to respond, as she has sent very positive emails following the job offer (smiley faces and the like). Thank you for your insight!