# Verbally accepted but no offer letter

Tags: hiring-process, ireland

I interviewed and discussed my salary with the design manager in one of the good companies in Ireland. The manager informed me that he will give me the contract after getting signature from the vice-president. 
It has been more than 2 months the vice-president didn't sign and whenever I ask the manager regarding my contract he says "I didn't get any feedback from VP".

Could someone please give me their opinions on this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accepted Job Offer, Now No Contact](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136194/accepted-job-offer-now-no-contact)

Comment: Sounds like bad communication within this company.  Manager wants you but VP doesn't agree.  Is the Manager trying to leverage pressure on the VP and using you to weight his argument. Is the tail wagging the dog? Not a great company to work for possibly!

Comment: I know this is a year old, but for anyone in a similar situation, just imagine what salary increase and promotion discussions will be like at this company.... RUN AWAY!

Answer (score 26):

> Could someone please give me their opinions on this case.

In my opinion, you don't have this job yet.

And since they haven't managed to get feedback from the VP for more than two months, you may never get this job.

If I were you, I'd continue the job search. If a formal offer ever arrives, you can decide what you would like to do at that time.

Comment: Hi, Now he says "I still not got sign-off  to give you a written offer". What does this mean?

Answer (score 13):

> The manager informed me that he will give me the contract after getting signature from Vice president.

Great, at which point you thank them, and then continue the job search. Until you have something delivered to you in writing, you don't have a job offer.

> It has been more than 2 months the vice president didn't sign and whenever I ask the manager regarding my contract he says " I didn't get any feedback from VP".

At 2 months, I'd give up entirely, stop chasing and treat it as a lost cause. Not worth any more time sunk into that IMHO. (I'd also never be applying to that company again.)

Comment: Hi, Now he says "I still not got sign-off  to give you a written offer". What does this mean?

Comment: @tisheebird It means you still don't have a written offer, he's making excuses, and I'm even more convinced than before you should just give up entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the company is just EXTREMELY slow, but you should assume that you didn't get the job and interview at other places in the meantime.

A verbal offer means nothing, especially if it hasn't been approved from the person in charge.

Comment: Hi, Now he says "I still not got sign-off  to give you a written offer". What does this mean?

Comment: The position or your employment are not approved by management yet. Search for another job in the meantime. You have no official offer yet and it's unclear, if you ever get a offer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if you haven’t received a start date, a written contract or a written or verbal declaration of when you will receive either of those things, within a week, you haven’t been hired and possibly will never be hired.  After two months, I’d move that from “possibly” to “almost definitely”.

I don’t know why the manager isn’t being more definitive, but if it was me, I wouldn’t be particularly interested in working for them even if they did come up with a contract.  The manager has just shown that delaying determining if you were hired for two months is perfectly acceptable, how will pay raises, times off or conflict with others be treated?

Comment: Hi, Now he says "I still not got sign-off  to give you a written offer". What does this mean?

Comment: @tisheebird: it has several meanings.  1) I do not have the authority to hire you or to say when you might be hired, 2) I wish you to believe that I wish to hire you, 3) I will not dispute with authority, and by implication 4) I do not care how this delay effects you.